# How would I make meaningful comparisons between the turnover rates of two groups?

Tags: sample-size

I am working with a medical clinic to develop a residency program for certified medical assistants (CMAs). The clinic would eventually like to know whether the residency program is successful in reducing turnover among CMAs. The turnover rates of CMAs who did not complete the residency program will be compared to those who did. Even though no data has been collected yet (as the program has yet to be implemented), cohort sizes will be small. Thus, there will be a vast difference in the number of CMAs who completed the program and those who did not. What test can I use to make a meaningful comparison between the turnover rates of the two groups?

Comment: What is your level of statistical experience?  This will help me suggest something useful and consider possible limitations.

Comment: @DemetriPananos I have taken a few graduate-level courses in statistics.

Comment: I assume here turnover means leaving the job, right?

Comment: @DemetriPananos Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm reading, it seems like you can use survival analysis.

There are two groups: Those who take the residency program and those who do not.  Measure their tenure in their role until they leave.  Naturally, some CMAs will still be in their role at the conclusion of data collection, and they will be censored.  Survival analysis can account for this.

Plot Kaplan-Meir curves for each group and compare them accordingly (either by log-rank test, or just visually.  Depending on how much data you can collect, you may have small statistical power and might want to opt to estimate survival times).

The strength of the causal inference here will be questionable, but it might be good enough evidence for the clinic (as opposed to science at large).

Hope this is helpful